# R error: arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a long list containing entries (genus/species) such as:

```
Escherichia coli
Bacillus anthracis
Aquiflexum balticum
```

There is a package in R called `myTAI` that has a function called `taxonomy()`. This function takes individual genus/species combination and spits some useful info. The function is called like this:

```
library(myTAI)
taxonomy(organism = "Escherichia coli", 
         db       = "ncbi",
         output   = "classification")
```

In order to paste a list of entries (instead of doing them individually), I used:

```
my_result <- sapply(my_list, function(a) taxonomy(organism = a, db = "ncbi", output = "classification"))
```

where `my_list` contains a long list of genus/species entries.

It works nicely however, when I try to convert the list to a .csv file with the following command:

```
write.csv(my_list, file = "./some_path/mylist.csv")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(`Escherichia\coli` = list(name = c("cellular organisms",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 8, 1, 10
```

I guess the reason is that `my_list` doesn't have the matching rows/column number. But I don't know how to fix it? I'd simply like the results to be exported to a tab/comma-delimited text file which I'll be able to manipulate easily.

Thank you in advance,
TP

Comment: How exactly do you want to transform these results to a CSV file? What exactly is the desired result? Show what you expect the resulting CSV file to look like.

Comment: You cannot export a nested list of objects with `write.csv()` but flat data structures like matrix or dataframe. Consider looping through your list for csv output.

Comment: @Parfait Sure you can, if the lengths match up, as the error said, right? I'm looking at `L = list(list(a = 1:2), list(b = 3:4)); write.csv(L)`

Comment: @MrFlick : I don't have a predefined aspect in mind. Normally, each object have is composed of max 10 rows and three columns. Perhaps, paste them side by side?

could it be possible to put "NA" for every missing value in order to have the correct length?

Comment: Well the error message means R doesn't know what to do either. If you don't know exactly what the desired output is, then there's not much we can do for you.

Comment: You're right, I haven't been explicit enough. Actually, the list (right now) contains 8 dataframes, and each dataframe is x observations of y variables. Is is possible to export individual dataframes side-by-side in a tab-separated file for example?